# SELECT DISTINCT query with numeric totals of other field for each distinct

Tags: sql, ms-access, jdbc, ms-access-2010

How do I write the following SELECT  query in an MS Access 2010 database?

Here is the situation:  Kids in school get put in detention for bad behavior.  Some parents have numerous kids.  **How can I get a list of parents that has the total number of detentions earned by all of that parent's kids?**

Here is the data structure: `BadParentsTable` has fields `ChildName`, `ParentName` and `NumberOfDetentions`.  ChildName and ParentName are text datatype.  NumberOfDetentions is number datatype.  Sample data looks like;

```
ChildName     ParentName    NumberOfDetentions  
Sally         GeorgeP        12
Fred          SamL           2
Sue           GeorgeP        5
Joe           SamL           10
```

The results should therefore be:

```
GeorgeP    17
SamL       12
```

Let's assume each child has only one parent.

**I guess I would try `SELECT DISTINCT ParentName FROM BadParentsTable`, but how do I write the SQL to get the sum of each parent's `NumberOfDetentions`?**

I am running this native query from Java using JDBC, so it is really more like: `ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT DISTINCT ParentName FROM BadParentsTable");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  ParentName,
  SUM(NumberOfDetentions) AS TotalDetentions
FROM test_table
GROUP BY ParentName
```

[Here's a SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f25c/2) (in MySQL, but this is pretty straightforward SQL)

Comment: Thank you and +1.  I am marking this as the answer because you answered the question.  However, are you kind enough to show additional variations for `ORDER BY TotalDetentions DESC` and `WHERE TotalDetentions >15`?  I am not sure what order to put the extra terms in.

Comment: Those answers may be a bit more specific to MySQL or TSQL, I hardly ever use MS Access.  Hopefully this will get you moving in the right direction: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f25c/5  Good luck!